# centos 6.2 grub fails with a black screen with a blinking cursor, but works when manually entering boot command line

Tags: centos6, grub

At $work we have a custom install of CentOS 6.2 (a pre-prepped image with a reduced set of packages).

The normal CentOS 6.2 install works fine.

The custom one fails to boot as follows:

- grub starts up and displays the defined boot options
- if we let it continue and try to boot, it gives the "a black screen with a blinking cursor" which is symptomatic of not finding the kernel
- if we go to the grub command line and manually input exactly the same boot command as grub loaded from the grub.conf, the machine boots successfully.

my google-foo is failing here, anyone have suggestions or solution?

Comment: When you customize something, it is difficult to give meaningful input. Details on grub.conf would be useful. Was anything migrated from an older install?

Answer (score 2):

The initrd is actually *initramfs* in CentOS6 not *initrd* (as in CentOS5), so it was never finding the initrd to boot. (PEBCAK :( ).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest there are errors in your grub.conf. Try to diff your one with "normal Centos" one.